# run apt update and get E: Failed to fetch File has unexpected size (2572288 != 2581052). Mirror sync in progress

Tags: apt, updates

Good day!

I use local Ubuntu mirror repo to download software and security update, now when I run apt update command on a server, and it prompts the following error:

Err:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
File has unexpected size (2228224 != 2237636). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: xx.xxx.xx.x 80]
Hashes of expected file:

- Filesize:2237636 [weak]
- SHA256:53ff6687d2d7b881a42bb252d0420483c56dda25eb31957d4b02182bba3225e5
- SHA1:df28b37a3a7deb2e09ae2bcfcdecd590d2c8d6f8 [weak]
- MD5Sum:5bd4346c9d5d17625f15287c94d7ae5e [weak]
  Release file created at: Mon, 23 May 2022 22:52:13 +0000

My Ubuntu version is 18.04, I check apt sources.list setting not found any issue, do I need to wait until the repo sync finished then run apt update? or is something wrong?

Comment: *Mirror sync in progress* can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the mirror server run out of disk and stuck at some packages, I expand the root directory and run `nohup sudo apt-mirror &`, after `apt-mirror sync` completed, then run `apt update` command again, it works like a charm.